# Can I take orthodontic wires in my hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I'm wearing braces and will spend a few months in another country. In order for my treatment not to be interrupted, my orthodontist will give me a few wires which look like this:

[image]

Is there any chance of them not being allowed in hand luggage? (The edges are quite sharp.)

Might be of relevance: I'll be flying from Europe to the US.

ADDED: I don't need them during the flight but I don't want to check them in, since in case they'd be examined without me (e.g. if TSA opens my suitcase), any slightest bending would invalidate the whole setting and make them useless.

Comment: I just saw this post and it's been 4 years ago. I stumble upon this because I've been searching with same situation too. So to the one who posted question about bringing some orthodontic wires, I wanna know how did it go? Did you able to bring your orthodontic archwire on your hand luggage or carryon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a note from your doctor. You can even take syringes on board if they are a medical necessity.

Comment: "A medical necessity" during the flight or in general? I don't need them during the flight but I don't want to check them in, since in case they'd be examined without me (e.g. if TSA opens my suitcase), any slightest bending would invalidate the whole setting and make them useless.

Comment: In general. These are needed by you, for your braces, during you trip in total, right? So they would be considered a medical necessity. Get a note from your orthodontist and get on with life.